# Seeking open source service for points of interest near by/within airport

Tags: geospatial, geocoding, open-source

Is there open source api for reverse geocoding the restaurants or hospitals near by or within a given airport?

Answer (score 1):

You can use OpenStreetMap (OSM) with the [OverpassAPI](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Overpass_API) to check for POIs in a specific area. To test around, I recommend using  [Overpass Turbo](https://overpass-turbo.eu/)